# process-exporter with alert rules in prometheus when process using too much CPU

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-process-exporter

i am using process-exporter to monitor process, then alert when a process using too much CPU.

This is my monitor CPU code in prometheus dashboard

```
sum(rate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~"$processes",instance="$host", mode=~"system|user"}[20s])) by (groupname, instance)
```

i have try to write alert with this (test for 10% CPU first)

```yaml
- name: process
  rules:
  - alert: CPUProcess
    expr: sum(rate(namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total[20s])) by (groupname, instance) > 10
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: "(instance {{ $labels.instance }}) use too much CPU"
      description: "Process (instance {{ $labels.groupname }}) use high CPU"
```

But seem like it doesn't work (another alert can work normal), can you give me a advice, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by changed to `namedprocess_namegroup_cpu_seconds_total{groupname=~".+", mode=~"system"} > 10`